# How to get exact rows count of particular column in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get exact row count of specified column

Example: Table

```
Name            Id          Age
_______________________________
  Jon           1           30
 Merry          2           40
 William                    50
 David
```

There are 4 rows in table but i want to count ID column.

I am using below query to achieve it

```
select count(Id) from table;
```

But its returning 4 and I know why it is returning 4 but I want output as 2 because there are only two rows in Id column.

How can i achieve it?

Comment: Your query should work. `COUNT(expression)` counts all rows for which the expression is not null. What I assume here is a flaw in your data model. Can it be that your ID column is not numeric as it should be, but a string instead and the gaps that we are seeing are not nulls, but empty strings (`''`). (On a side note: A table's ID should never be nullable anyway. It should uniquely identify a row. It is typically the table's primary key.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count(Id) from table where id>0;
```

Comment: One important part to this: your database field has to be nullable. If it's a string, you should use id != ""

Comment: @Edwin Dijk If the id is nullable, we can still use id > 0 to deem it false. `select if(null>0,'T','F');` And for an empty string, Mysql treats it as 0.  `select if(''=0,'T','F');`

Comment: @blabla_bingo I stand corrected :-)

Answer (score 0):

with the help of @blabla_bingo and @Edwin Dijk finally i have achieved it by below query

```
select count(Id) from table where Id!="";
```

Comment: If you store numeric IDs in a text column, you are doing it wrong. Fix the data model and make that column numeric. Then your original query works as it should. As to your new query: Double quotes are meant to denote names in SQL. Use single quotes for string literals instead.

Comment: Thank you for the mention, but I agree with @ThorstenKettner. Definitely especially a column called "id" would be assumed by everyone to be at least numeric and probably an integer (and probably unique and probably auto incremented).